# React Can I set button to do different things based on dropdown menu selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown menu on a form. Once the user chooses a selection, I'd like for the Submit button to do different requests based on the dropdown menu item selection. For example, if user chooses Apples, then Submit button fires a function1, while if user chooses Bananas, then Submit button fires a function2.

I have a parent component that looks like this:

```
class Container extends React.PureComponent {
  _onSubmit = (date) => {
    this.props.function1({
      paramA: this.props.paramA,
      paramB: this.props.paramB,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
         <div>
            <DownloadForm
              dataSetName="Apples"
              buttonText="Request Report"
              onSubmit={this._onSubmit}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, my `DownloadForm` component, which is nested here, will have a dropdown menu, and based on the dropdown menu's item, will have the `onSubmit` do something with a function2, which takes different parameters too.

I'm not sure how to do design this. I have 1 page as above, with the parent component that passes the `onSubmit` to it's nested component, and fires away to function1. I have another page as above, with the parent component also passing an `onSubmit` to the nested component, which fires away to function2.

How do I make it so that the dropdown menu item selection, inside the nested component, will then change it's button's `onSubmit` to fire away to function1 or function2 based on the dropdown menu item selected?

I hope my issue is clear.

Comment: Instead, make the user's selection render a different subcomponent that does what it needs to do. Also, why `PureComponent` instead of `Component`? Do you _need_ that `shouldComponentUpdate()` function? Because from the looks of it, you don't. (and to further the React questions, your onSubmit is going to do unexpected things. Either use `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);` in the constructor, or use `onSubmit={() => this.onSubmit()}` in your JSX. And probably remove that leading `_` because that does nothing, and just makes the code less standard-JS-that-everyone-can-read.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you mean by "make the user's selection render a different subcomponent that does what it needs to do." 

What should this subcomponent contain? And that's for the suggested changes, I'll do that now.

Comment: You say "I have a dropdown menu on a form. Once the user chooses a selection, I'd like for the Submit button to do different request" but instead of making different requests, have an `onChange` on your `select`, have that update your app's state, and have whatever renders your submit button render a _different_ submit button that does what you need it to do based on the app state.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans appreciate it. That makes it more clear.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If you have any insight on how I can think like this, and come up with the way you designed this, please let me know. It's so clear when you wrote it, but I feel dumb for wracking my brain for so long and not thinking of this.

Comment: My advice would be to run through the [official React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) (even if you've already done so in the past) because it's really quite good at giving you all the basics of "how to React" without dumbing things down. Code along (don't copy-paste) and you end up getting a lot of value out of the exercise. Probably the best 1~2 hours you can possibly spend if you're doing any kind of React development.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've done that previously, but before I was familiar at all with React. I'll do it again today. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a state that records the value of the dropdown selection inside the parent component. Inside `_onSubmit()` you check the state.

```
if (this.state.selection == "Apples") { 
  function1(param1, param2)
}
```

Here is a quick bit of code I put together that should get you started. It also takes into account some of @Mikes' comments

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: null
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (date) => {
    if (this.state.selection == "Apples") { 
      this.props.function1({
        paramA: this.props.paramA,
        paramB: this.props.paramB,
      });
    }
    if (this.state.selection == "Bananas") { 
      this.props.function2({
        paramA: this.props.paramA,
        paramB: this.props.paramB,
      });
    }
  };

  handleSelectionChange = (selection) => {
    this.setState({selection: selection})
  }

  render() {
    return (
         <div>
            <Dropdown
              onChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
            />
            <DownloadForm
              dataSetName="Apples"
              buttonText="Request Report"
              onSubmit={this._onSubmit}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'm close to getting it working. Just can't get the dropdown to actually select a value! But this snippet makes things clearer.

Comment: Hmm so I'm having issues still. My structure is similar to yours, but in my nested component, `<DownloadForm>`, the `onSubmit` prop doesn't seem to be changing after I choose my selection from the menu. The state in the parent component is changing, -- `this.state.selection` updates to Apples or Bananas.

I think it's because I have my dropdown is inside the nested component itself. So I have the `onSelect` on the dropdown, which is located inside the `<DownloadForm>` rather than being its own component. Is that the problem?

Comment: Nope just had a spelling mistake in my `this.state.selection == "Bananas"` check. Thank you! If you have any comments on how I can think like this, and come up with the way you designed this, please let me know. It's so clear when you wrote it, but I feel dumb for wracking my brain for so long and not thinking of this.

Comment: @usershrub123 Sorry for the late reply. I'm glad you got it working!

Writing react code usually comes with experience. As you become struggle through problems and become more familiar with react it will come to you. 

There is usually many ways to solve a problem. Mike was suggesting a different way than I laid out. Doing tutorials thoroughly and not copy-pasting is usually a good way to build a strong react base

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll keep struggling through and come out the better I hope. Appreciate it.